# Using list2env() in chained operation (%>%) to assign objects from named list into function environment

Tags: r, magrittr

I have a child function that returns a named list, and I would like to use `list2env` to assign those values as objects in my parent function. The issue that I am running into is that when I try to chain list2env using magrittr pipes, the resulting behavior is unexpected and does not seem to line up with the behavior observed when I assign objects to the global environment in this manner. I feel that assigning them to the global environment is more dangerous, so I would like to confine them to my parent function environment.

PS: Yes I understand that it is probably a better solution to just use the objects in the named list but the larger context of my issue requires this solution instead: Essentially I have a situation where I am running a function over multiple directories to load an `RData` file with multiple objects in my parent function environment. However, in some directories this file has not been created and instead must be compiled using the child function, which I want to mimic the behavior of loading the `RData` file by building those objects from the files in the directory and then assigning them to the parent function environment.

```r
#setup
rm(list=ls())
require(magrittr)

#make a dummy parent function
parentFx <- function() {

  #make a dummy internal function that will return a named list that we want to assign to the parent fx environment
  makeList <- function() {

    message('making list')

    #return objects in a named list (we can assign this to the parent env using list2env)
    list('a'=1, 'b'=2, 'c'=3) %>% 
      return

  }

  #build the list and then pass it to list2env using a pipe
  makeList() %>% 
    list2env(., envir = environment()) 

  #check environment for desired changes
  message('checking it once')
  ls() %in% c('a','b','c') %>% 
    any %>% 
    print

  #build the list and save it
  l <- makeList()

  #then pass it on to list2env
  list2env(l, envir=environment())

  #now we see the list has been assigned to the fx environment
  message('checking it twice')
  ls() %in% c('a','b','c') %>% 
    any %>% 
    print

  #as a final test, we can observe that this behavior does not seem to apply to the global environment
  #build the list and then pass it to list2env using a pipe (this time use global)
  makeList() %>% 
    list2env(., envir = .GlobalEnv) 

}

#run parent function
parentFx()

#check global environment for changes
ls() %in% c('a','b','c') %>% any %>% print
```

I would expect that both of my `list2env` calls that use `environment()` should have the same result, yet it seems that only when I save the results of my child function to a list and then pass that into `list2env` am I observing the expected result.

Furthermore, when I pass `.GlobalEnv`, the global environment is modified as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because a different environment is used inside the pipe stream. This can be seen in the simple example I created.

```r
library("magrittr")
environment()
#> <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
1 %>% {print(environment())}
#> <environment: 0x0000000009900598>
```

And, your function works when using the "correct" environment inside your `parentFx()`.

```r
parentFx <- function() {

    env <- environment()

    makeList <- function() {
        list('a'=1, 'b'=2, 'c'=3)
    }

    makeList() %>% 
        list2env(., envir = environment()) 

    message('checking it once')
    ls() %in% c('a','b','c') %>% 
        any %>% 
        print

    makeList() %>% 
        list2env(., envir = env) 

    message('checking it twice')
    ls() %in% c('a','b','c') %>% 
        any %>% 
        print
}

parentFx()
#> checking it once
#> [1] FALSE
#> checking it twice
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Very interesting, I did not realize that piped environments had this behavior. More info here: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pipe-r-tutorial.